# como centro un div dentro de section, margin auto no me funciona

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

estoy haciendo un sitio pero al div contenedor le pongo margin auto y no funciona

```css
.servicios{
  background: #fff;
  height: 750px;
  clear: both;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: auto;

}
.title-service{
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  clear: both;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
}
.servicios hr{
height: 10px;
background: #E9CA1E;
border: none;
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contenido-serv{
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  float: left;
}
.aut-ind{
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width:300px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.importacion-ind{
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width:300px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.asesoramiento{
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width:300px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="servicios">
     <p class="title-service">SERVICIOS</p>
     <hr class="linea-servicio">
     <div class="contenido-serv">
  <div class="aut-ind">
    <article class="">
    <img src="industria.jpg" alt="" height=250px width="300px"  >
    <p class="titulos">AUTOMATIZACION INDUSTRIAL</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
          <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
          <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
          <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
          <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
       </p>
       </article>
  </div>
  <div class="importacion-ind">
      <img src="container.jpg" alt=""  height="250px" width="300px">
      <p class="titulos">IMPORTACION</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
       <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
       <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
       <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
       <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
     </p>
  </div>
      <div class="asesoramiento">
         <img src="asesoramiento.jpg" alt="" height="250px" width="300px">
         <p class="titulos">ASESORAMIENTO TECNICO</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
         <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
         <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
         <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que pretendes hacer, puedes agrupar los estilos de los tres elementos en una sola clase común (utilicé `sub-section`), pues ninguno tiene algo en particular.

En cuanto a centrar dichos "div", si quitas la línea `float: left`, funciona como lo quieres.

```css
.servicios{
  background: #fff;
  height: 750px;
  clear: both;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: auto;

}
.title-service{
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  clear: both;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
}
.servicios hr{
height: 10px;
background: #E9CA1E;
border: none;
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contenido-serv{
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  float: left;
}
.servicios .sub-section {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="servicios">
     <p class="title-service">SERVICIOS</p>
     <hr class="linea-servicio">
     <div class="contenido-serv">
  <div class="aut-ind sub-section">
    <article class="">
    <img src="industria.jpg" alt="" height=250px width="300px"  >
    <p class="titulos">AUTOMATIZACION INDUSTRIAL</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
          <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
          <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
          <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
          <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
       </p>
       </article>
  </div>
  <div class="importacion-ind sub-section">
      <img src="container.jpg" alt=""  height="250px" width="300px">
      <p class="titulos">IMPORTACION</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
       <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
       <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
       <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
       <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
     </p>
  </div>
      <div class="asesoramiento sub-section">
         <img src="asesoramiento.jpg" alt="" height="250px" width="300px">
         <p class="titulos">ASESORAMIENTO TECNICO</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
         <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
         <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
         <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

EDICIÓN:

Teniendo en cuenta que el OP había explicado mal el problema, modifico la solución y utilizo Flexbox para "centrar" los tres div de forma horizontal:

```css
.servicios{
  background: #fff;
  height: 750px;
  clear: both;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: auto;

}
.title-service{
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  clear: both;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
}
.servicios hr{
height: 10px;
background: #E9CA1E;
border: none;
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contenido-serv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.servicios .sub-section {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="servicios">
     <p class="title-service">SERVICIOS</p>
     <hr class="linea-servicio">
     <div class="contenido-serv">
  <div class="aut-ind sub-section">
    <article class="">
    <img src="industria.jpg" alt="" height=250px width="300px"  >
    <p class="titulos">AUTOMATIZACION INDUSTRIAL</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
          <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
          <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
          <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
          <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
       </p>
       </article>
  </div>
  <div class="importacion-ind sub-section">
      <img src="container.jpg" alt=""  height="250px" width="300px">
      <p class="titulos">IMPORTACION</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
       <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
       <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
       <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
       <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
     </p>
  </div>
      <div class="asesoramiento sub-section">
         <img src="asesoramiento.jpg" alt="" height="250px" width="300px">
         <p class="titulos">ASESORAMIENTO TECNICO</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
         <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
         <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
         <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: si gracias por responder pero si le quito el float:left se centran pero necesito que esten centrados horizontalmente :)

Comment: A qué te refieres? los tres centrados en una sola línea? No es claro lo que quieres.

Comment: disculpa, si exactamente ......................

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta, solucionando ahora el problema con Flexbox.

Comment: muchas gracias ;)

Answer (score 0):

Espero poder ayudar, pero te recomendaría nombrar mejor tus clases en tu html, para que evites repetir código innecesario, suerte con tu proyecto, cualquier duda no dudes en consultarme.

```css
.servicios {
  background: #fff;
  height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-service {
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.servicios hr {
  height: 10px;
  background: #E9CA1E;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contenido-serv {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box{
  width: 300px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="servicios">
  <p class="title-service">SERVICIOS</p>
  <hr class="linea-servicio">
  <div class="contenido-serv">
    <div class="box aut-ind">
      <article class="">
        <img src="industria.jpg" >
        <p class="titulos">AUTOMATIZACION INDUSTRIAL</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
          <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
          <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
          <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
          <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="box importacion-ind">
      <img src="container.jpg">
      <p class="titulos">IMPORTACION</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
        <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
        <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box asesoramiento">
      <img src="asesoramiento.jpg">
      <p class="titulos">ASESORAMIENTO TECNICO</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        <br>adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget
        <br>dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
        <br>penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```